# Knockout bindings not updating in IE 8

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have a page that displays a list of items in the DB and a text box to add a new a new item.  When the page is first rendered the list is displayed properly in IE, but when I add a new item the list is not updated in IE 8.  This works correctly in chrome.  Here is my code:

```
self.ListOfDepartments.GetListOfAllDepartments = function () {
    $.getJSON('/Department/ListAllDepartments', function (data) {
        var mapped = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
        self.ListOfDepartments(mapped);
    });
};

self.AddDepartmentModel.AddDepartment = function () {
    self.errors = ko.validation.group(this, { deep: true, observable: false });
    if (self.AddDepartmentModel.errors().length == 0) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Department/Add/",
            type: 'post',
            data: ko.toJSON(self.AddDepartmentModel),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (result) {
                $('#success').html('Department Added Successfully.');
                $("#success").dialog({
                    dialogClass: 'noclose',
                    autoOpen: true,
                    show: "blind",
                    hide: "explode",
                    modal: true,
                    open: function(event, ui) {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $('#success').dialog('close');
                        }, 3000);
                    }
                });
                Department.DepartmentName(null);
                Department.DepartmentName.isModified(false);
                self.ListOfDepartments.GetListOfAllDepartments();

            }
        });
    } else {
        self.AddDepartmentModel.errors.showAllMessages();
        return;
    }
};
```

HTML:

```
    <div data-bind="foreach: ListOfDepartments()">
        <div data-bind="text: DepartmentName" class="margin textStyle"></div>
    </div>
```

When GetLIstOfAllDepartments is called if the add was successful the list of my page does not update in IE.  Is there something special that needs to be done for IE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution.  IE is caching ajax requests just turn off caching:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
});
```